# Rails Paperclip Gem File Not Uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

I installed the Paperclip gem but the file is not uploading correctly. I am trying to upload a file into my Contract model. Since put in a validation for presence of an image file, I can tell that the file did not upload because I get the "Image can't be blank error". Furthermore, if I take out that validation, the file doesn't show up in my show.html.erb view.

Here is my Contract model:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image
    validates_presence_of :image
    has_many :task_orders, :dependent => :destroy
    validates_uniqueness_of :id
    validates_presence_of :id
    self.primary_key = :id
    validates :awardAmount, :numericality => true

end
```

Here is my Contract form:

```
<%= form_for(@contract, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @contract.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contract.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contract     from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @contract.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
     </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Contract Number" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Contract Name'%><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Award Date" %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :awardDate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Expiration Date"%><br>
    <%= f.date_select :expirationDate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Award Amount"%><br>
    <%= f.text_field :awardAmount %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Image"%><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And lastly here is my contract/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Contract ID:</strong>
  <%= @contract.id %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Contract Name:</strong>
  <%= @contract.name %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Award Date:</strong>
  <%= @contract.awardDate %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Expiration Date:</strong>
  <%= @contract.expirationDate %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Award Amount:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@contract.awardAmount) %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Obligated Amount:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@contract.obligatedAmount) %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Invoiced to Date:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@contract.invoicedAmount) %>
</p>
<% if @contract.image? %>
<p>
  <strong>Attachment:</strong>
  <%= link_to @contract.image.url, @contract.image.url %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: try change the form  <%= form_for @contract,{},:html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>

Comment: That didn't work... it gave me a horrendous error instead @ramamoorthy_villi

Comment: Can you post your `ContractController`?

Comment: has_attached_file :photo
validates_presence_of :photo @JKen13579

Comment: No I mean the `contracts` controller, specifically the `contract_params` method.

Comment: ahhhh, that make sense now! I forgot to add "image" to the params require method. thank you!! @JKen13579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we established in the comments, you forgot to add `:image` to your `contract_params` method. Classic `strong_params` mistake. It happens to us all.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your strong params declaration in your controller and append :image to one of the whitelisted attributes.

```
def contract_params
  params.require(:section).permit(:id, :name,:awardDate, :expirationDate, :awardAmount,  :image)
end
```

This allows for whitelisting to your the new :image attribute migrated by Paperclip.